# Sending out Radio Frequency (RF) Signals with Android App

Tags: android, radio-transmission

Is it possible to built an app which sends out RF signals? Is it possible to control the exact frequency? So each button would send different frequency signal? How far those signals usually reach?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it is for andriod app

Comment: http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/98672.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you need some external RF hardware - check out [GNU radio](http://gnuradio.org/) and the general subject area of [Software Defined Radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it is for andriod app

Comment: OK - in that case the answer is no, assuming that you're just talking about Android *phones* and not Android in general ?

Comment: The answer is relevant for Android apps, you can use NDK.

Comment: Probably not for Android *phones* though which I suspect is what the OP is *really* asking about ?

Comment: Paul - you say the answer it no while Amigable Superman says NDK would so the work;

Comment: Please clarify what your target (hardware) platform is

Comment: Do you know an app that actually does it today? I am looking for proof of concept; I don't mind paying for developing simple app with 3 buttons, where each buttons sends out different radio frequency

Comment: my target hardware would be a mobile phone like samsung galaxy or any other mobile that works with android

Comment: I doubt there is any way of doing this with the phone on its own - you'd still need something like the GNU Radio hardware connected via USB.

Answer (score 5):

The app itself will not send RF signal. 
The app is the logic thay may control a RF hardware.

There are many hardware devices that do this for you.

Arduino could be a simple and cheap solution

to have an idea how a similar project could work look [here.](http://www.glacialwanderer.com/hobbyrobotics/?p=291)