# is it possible to use android cellphones Telecommunication hardware to transmit and receive radio messages?

Tags: android, telecommunication, rtl-sdr

Is there a way to turn android phone 4G hardware to a module that can transmit any radio messages or make p2p connection with another phone?

Comment: Actual phone can receive radio message, and apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477241/sending-out-radio-frequency-rf-signals-with-android-app) can help you to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean you want Android to take control of the radio HW in the phone and transit and receive on non GSM/3G/4G networks - this is not possible at this time AFAIK.

What you are describing sounds like Software Defined Radio - there is a link to some info to that in the answer flagged by Elikill58 in the comments: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio

There is available external HHW that you can control via Android which will do what you want - e.g. RTL_SDR (https://www.rtl-sdr.com)

You can see an example app that can control this to receive FM radio on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.jajae.fmradio